# AWS Lambda with typescript getting Cannot read property of undefined inside async handler

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, es6-promise, aws-sam

Typescript newbie here. I am working on an AWS Lambda function by using typescript with classes. I am exporting an `async` handler at the end. When I invoke my function from AWS SAM CLI then I am getting error of;

> {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'test' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined","    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/src/lambda/create-cost-lambda.js:12:56)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]}

**create-cost-lambda.ts**

```
class CreateCostLambda {
    private readonly foobarRepository: FoobarRepository;

    constructor() {
        this.foobarRepository = new FoobarRepository();
    }

    async handler(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2) : Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> {
        const result = await this.foobarRepository.test();
        console.log(result);

        return {
            body: JSON.stringify(result),
            statusCode: 200,
        };
    }
}

export const { handler } = new CreateCostLambda();
```

Here is a very basic class represents a repository.

**foobar-repository.ts**

```
export class FoobarRepository {
    private readonly awesomeValue: string;

    constructor() {
        this.awesomeValue = 'John Doe';
    }

    async test(): Promise<string> {
        return this.awesomeValue;
    }
}
```

I am almost sure it is because of the way I am exporting the handler and how `aws-sam` internally runs the handler. But I might be wrong and it can be typescript thing that I am missing. Please let me know if you need more information and thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: `async handler(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2) : Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2>` needs to be an arrow function. You are losing context for you function. Write it like `handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2) : Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> => {..}`

Comment: @Townsheriff thanks for the approach. I was considering more of an Object Oriented way of implementation which is discussed in article https://blog.10pines.com/2019/07/23/writing-object-oriented-typescript-code-for-aws-lambda/. So, exporting handler with `bind` worked as expected. Something like; `export const createCostLambda = new CreateCostLambda();
export const handler = createCostLambda.handler.bind(createCostLambda);` Is it a bad approach for what I am asking? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want something like that. You need to bind otherwise you wont have access to context. I would go with just a function - `module.exports.handler = (...) => {...}`. Arrow functions bind the function to the context it self so you can write in your class arrow "methods" and it will work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG9oCMwCdoF5oAoBKXAPhQF9pyg

Comment: Thanks you right. I went with the approach of just using an arrow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is if you pass a function from an class, it loses it's reference to `this`.

I would solve this as follows:

```js
const createCostLambda = new CreateCostLambda();
export const handler = createCostLambda.handler.bind(createCostLambda);
```

You can also ask yourself, does this need to be a class? The answer is: probably not. There's nothing gained from this in your sample.

```js
const foobarRepository = new FoobarRepository();
export async function handler(event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2) : Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> {
   const result = await foobarRepository.test();
   console.log(result);

   return {
     body: JSON.stringify(result),
     statusCode: 200,
   };
}
```

Fewer lines, no unneeded state. Javascript is not Java =)

Comment: yeah you are right. I thought if I would use handler method from a class it would be better for testing purposes (I am Java guy :) ). So, I went with the approach by exporting a function. Thanks again